# php date_diff in hours

Tags: php, datetime, date

How is it possible to make the code below convert days in hours?

```
$timestart = date_create('02/11/2011' . $row->timestart); //$row->timestart returns time in 00:00:00 format
$timestop = date_create('02/11/2011' . $row->timestop); //$row->timestop returns time in 00:00:00 format

date_add($timestop, date_interval_create_from_date_string('2 days')); //add 2 days

$date_diff = date_diff($timestart, $timestop);

echo "Timespan: ";
echo $date_diff->format('%h hours');
echo "<br />";
```

How can I get the `hours:minutes:seconds` elapsed? I'm trying to stay with the `date_diff` function.

Comment: You should be using the object style of `DateTime`.

Comment: @Truth, what is wrong with the procedural style? It seems to give the same results.

Comment: It does give the same results, it's just much easier to work with DateTime objects than with procedural functions. It also [looks nicer](https://gist.github.com/2942405)

Comment: `If $date_diff->format('H:i:s')` doesn't work, you may have some sort of input formatting issue to begin with, from which it doesn't convert it back properly. For example make sure there is a space between the date and the timestart/timestop variables in the first two lines

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result of date_diff() is an object of [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) class. Such object has a very useful property - `$days`: it's total number of days between the starting and the ending dates. Besides, it stores (as its public properties) the difference in hours, minutes and seconds.

So, I suppose, what you need is just extract values of these properties from $date_diff variable, then add `24*$days` to the hours number. ) All this can be wrapped into a simple function:

```
function hms_date_diff(DateInterval $date_diff) {
  $total_days = $date_diff->days;
  $hours      = $date_diff->h;
  if ($total_days !== FALSE) {
    $hours += 24 * $total_days;
  }
  $minutes    = $date_diff->i;
  $seconds    = $date_diff->s;
  return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
}
```

As for DateDiff::format, the [doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) says...

> The DateInterval::format() method does not recalculate carry over
>   points in time strings nor in date segments.

Answer (score 1):

The `DateInterval` object, returned by `date_diff` stores each period of time separately, seconds, minutes, hours, days, months and years.

Since the difference is 2 days, the hours property is 0, which is what you get.