# DIFF from two dates and get hours and minutes

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Time diff in minutes between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929612/time-diff-in-minutes-between-2-dates)
>   [php date_diff in hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066503/php-date-diff-in-hours)

i have:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2012-12-01 10:40:00');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2012-12-03 12:00:00');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%1 day %h hours %i minutes');
```

this working ok, but how can i show only hours and minutes? For this example should be:

**49 hours 10 minutes**

Comment: and there is very likely a couple more dupes. Please use the search function before asking. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the PHP manual:

> Note:
>
> The DateInterval::format() method does not recalculate carry over points in time strings nor in date segments. This is expected because it is not possible to overflow values like "32 days" which could be interpreted as anything from "1 month and 4 days" to "1 month and 1 day".

In other words, the `DateInterval` class won't do what you're asking for on its own; you'd have to do the calculation yourself.

Something like this should do it:

```
$hours = $interval->h + ($interval->d*24);
print "{$hours} hours ".$interval->format('%i minutes');
```